# DBus "Operation already in progress" error on return from suspend

Tags: xfce4-power-manager

Every time I return from suspend I get the following error:

```
"GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Failed: Operation already in progress"
```

To be clear, it's not causing any issues for me as far as I can tell, I'm trying to understand the cause of it and what can be done about it.
Catching all notifications, I got a full log of the message:

```
method call sender=:1.39 -> dest=:1.213 serial=27 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=Notify
   string "xfce4-power-manager"
   string ""
   string "Power Manager"
   string "GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Failed: Operation already in progress"
         string "urgency"
         string "icon_data"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by a double suspend command being sent to the system, after disabling suspend on lid close in xfce4-power-manager and the laptop still suspending, it was easier to troubleshoot.

in /etc/systemd/logind.conf, changing:

```
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
```

to:

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

seems to have fixed this issue...